# Compressing/combining rows in r df based on multiple conditions

Tags: r

I have a df containing the outputs of a simple game. Every 30 rows, the df switches to a new set of players. Here is a sample with just the first 2 sets of players:

```
> dput(stackdf)
structure(list(id = structure(list(`dataset_single$id` = c(20230420, 
20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 
20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 
20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 
20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 
20230420, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 
20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 
20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 
20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 
20230424, 20230424, 20230424)), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = "data.frame"), 
    round = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
    "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", 
    "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", 
    "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
    "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", 
    "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30"), win = c(1, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 0), sound = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 
    5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 1, 4, 8, 6, 7, 8, 5, 4, 8, 8, 8, 3, 4, 5, 
    5, 6, 5, 2, 5, 7, 4, 7, 6, 8, 5, 1, 8, 5, 3, 7, 6, 3, 6, 
    6, 5, 5, 8, 1, 6, 6, 5)), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The "win" column indicates the winner (p1=1, p2=0), and the "sound" column indicates the score of the winner for that round. As you can see, there are streaks where p1 might win a few rounds in a row, and then p2 wins several, etc. When there is a streak, I want to compress the streak so that it becomes one row, where the "sound" column takes a mean of the sound scores in that streak. For example, this:

| win | sound |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 0 | 4 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 6 |

would become:

| win | sound |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 0 | 2.5 |
| 1 | 3.67 |

There are 2 things making this tricky: 1.) the full df is huge, so I am seeking an automated solution (probably a for loop?); and 2.) I need to confine the program to one set of players at a time so that it does not think that rows 27:31 (for example) is one big streak (as row 31 is actually a new set of players).

Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the first `id` column is a nested dataframe inside a column. I have corrected it to a regular column.

```
stackdf$id <- stackdf$id$`dataset_single$id`
```

Here are two option using `dplyr` and `data.table` which follows the same logic. Use `data.table` option if you need more speed.

`dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

stackdf %>%
  group_by(id, cons_id = consecutive_id(win)) %>% 
  summarise(win = first(win), 
            sound = mean(sound),.groups = "drop")
```

`data.table` -

```
library(data.table)  

setDT(stackdf)
stackdf[, .(win = first(win), sound = mean(sound)), .(id, cons_id = rleid(win))]
```

`consecutive_id` in `dplyr` and `rleid` in `data.table` creates a unique identifier which increments every time the value changes.

Answer (score 1):

Finally it looks as a group and summarise task:
Note the first column looks like a nested list:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr) #> 1.1.0

stackdf %>%
  unnest(id) %>% 
  rename(id = `dataset_single$id`) %>% 
  mutate(x = consecutive_id(win), .by=id) %>% 
  summarise(mean_sound = mean(sound), .by = c(id, x, win)) %>% 
  select(-x)
```

```
  id   win mean_sound
      <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 20230420     1       1   
 2 20230420     0       1   
 3 20230420     1       1.5 
 4 20230420     0       1.5 
 5 20230420     1       2   
 6 20230420     0       1.5 
 7 20230420     1       2.75
 8 20230420     0       6   
 9 20230420     1       7   
10 20230420     0       8   
# … with 23 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```